# How to enumerate through a List<T> in C#

Tags: c#

i have the folowing data model

```
public class Model
{
    public String X { get; set; }
    public String Y { get; set; }

    public Model(String x, String y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

i have created a List of it's type as follows and added elements:

```
List<Model> list_model = new List<Model>();
```

i want to list the elements in it using a foreach/for loop:

```
(foreach Model m in list_model){
   String x=
   String y=
 }
```

such that the elements x and y are both listed.
How do i go about this?

Comment: `String x = m.X;` is probably what you are looking for

Comment: What to you mean by list x & y? Do you want to display them? Add them to a new collection?

Comment: If you explain the purpose of your loop, you'll likely get a much better solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
foreach(var m in list_model)
{
     string output = string.Format("x:{0}, y:{1}", m.X, m.Y);
     System.Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Edit : Or as Christ pointed you can use the more condensed version :

```
foreach(var m in list_model)
{
     System.Console.WriteLine("x:{0}, y:{1}", m.X, m.Y);
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` supports format strings. No need for the extra call to `string.Format`.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the answer, but since he seems to be learning the language, it might useful for him that this kind of magic be explicited.